# How to parse this string into json object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string

```
var str = '{"{\n  \"lightid\": \"ID1\",\n  \"brightness\": \"123\",\n  \"RGB\": \"1,2,3\"\n}":""}';
```

How do I parse it into JSON object?

Comment: Not a valid json.

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse()`, but your string is not a valid json

Comment: I know that's not a vaild json, how do i convert into a valid one so I can parse it ?

Comment: Why do you have an object key with an empty string as the value?

Comment: Actually that's the return result from the server. I need to validate and convert to valid json in order to parse it.

Comment: a json is {key : value} keep only the {object} in the first brackets.
your string looks more like {{object}:value} and this is wrong.

Comment: You need to fix this on the backend. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
JSON.parse('{\n  \"lightid\": \"ID1\",\n  \"brightness\": \"123\",\n  \"RGB\": \"1,2,3\"\n}');
```

Comment: It's different string than in question

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` string is malformed. Currently, it is:

```
var str = '{"{\n  \"lightid\": \"ID1\",\n  \"brightness\": \"123\",\n  \"RGB\": \"1,2,3\"\n}":""}';
```

which evaluates to

```
{"{
   "lightid": "ID1",
   "brightness": "123",
   "RGB": "1,2,3"
}":""}
```

You need to use:

```
var str = '{\n  \"lightid\": \"ID1\",\n  \"brightness\": \"123\",\n  \"RGB\": \"1,2,3\"\n}'
```

And use the default JSON parser:

```
var jsObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log("jsonObj.brightness", jsonObj.brightness);
```

It seems you will have a list of such values. In this case, the probable
construct will be:

```
var str = '[ {\n  \"lightid\": \"ID1\",\n  \"brightness\": \"123\",\n  \"RGB\": \"1,2,3\"\n}, \n {\n  \"lightid\": \"ID2\",\n  \"brightness\": \"246\",\n  \"RGB\": \"2,4,6\"\n} ]'
var jsArr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log("jsonObj[0].brightness", jsonObj[0].brightness);
```